# Creating a auto terminating main function

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The following program implements two array of threads.There are two thread functions student and teacher(I have not shown them here). My sample program is given below. I want to make a time limit(say 10 sec) after which the main thread will automatically exit no matter if others threads have completed or not.I also want to the current time every moment after starting of the program. How will I do that?

Sample code fragment:

```
int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread1[25];
    pthread_t thread2[6];
    int i;
    int id1[25];   //for students
    int id2[6];   //for teachers

    for(i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
          id1[i]=i;
          id2[i]=i;
          pthread_create(&thread1[i],NULL,student,(void*)&id1[i] );

          if(i<6)
          {
             pthread_create(&thread2[i],NULL,teacher,(void*)&id2[i]);
          }
    }



   for (i=0;i<25;i++)
   {
     pthread_join(thread1[i],NULL);  
     if(i<6)
     {
        pthread_join(thread2[i],NULL);
     }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

What additional things will I have to add to the above code to terminate the main thread after a certain time? (say: 10 seconds)

Comment: If the process exits, all (non detached) threads will be killed as well. So all you need is the timer.

Comment: how will I set the timer? Can you please show me a demo code? @Joachim Pileborg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pthread_timedjoin_np()` for this passing a `timespec` struct. You can set the struct to timeout after 10 seconds like this:

```
struct timespec tp;
tp.tv_sec = 10;
tp.tv_nsec = 0;
```

Then you change your calls to join `pthread_timedjoin_np(myThread, &tp)`. Regarding how you can get the current time, the simplest method is to use `gettimeofday` function.

Another perhaps simpler approach is to use a alarm. You can have a function which will exit the application. So you would do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void alarmhandler(int sig) {
  printf("Ten seconds passed, quitting!\n");
  exit(0);
}

int main() {
  int i, j;
  struct timeval end, start;
  signal(SIGALRM, alarmhandler);
  alarm(4);
  gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
  sleep(3); // simulate thread work
  gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
  long elapsed = (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000000 + end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec;
  printf("%f seconds elapsed!\n", (float)(elapsed)/1000000.0f);
  for(;;); // block indefinitely
}
```

Comment: You don't have to wait for all threads to complete, only the first one.

Comment: what is tp.tv_sec and tp.tv_nsec? what does they mean? @Linus

Comment: @user3114849 See [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_tryjoin_np.3.html) manual. But perhaps using an alarm would be simpler for you.

Comment: is there any way to print how much time remaining after every moment if I use the alarm? @Linus

Comment: @user3114849 What do you mean by "every moment"?

Comment: I mean inside each threads when they are working till the end of the main program(say after every 1 sec) @Linus

Comment: @user3114849 That's a non-related question to this topic and I suggest you accept my answer if it is helpful and post a new question on your described problem.

Comment: Check my post. There is a line "I also want to print the current time every moment after starting of the program" which is related to my question. There is no problem if you give answer in case of inside main function instead of inside threads.I will surely accept your answer if you kindly answer this. @Linus

Comment: @user3114849 See my updated example on how you can get the elapsed time. If you want to print it every second please see [this](https://ideone.com/QHtRDS) live example.